# Laravel put one value from the database in a session

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have a issue with the sessions in Laravel...
So I want to select some values from the database to show the user image via the session.

This is my LoginController, so when they log in, I give the session defined.

The query that I'm using:

```
$users_images = DB::table('users')->select('user_image.img')->join('user_image','user_image.uid','=','users.id')->get();
```

Now, I do hope the query is correct written, I want to select 'img' from the table 'user_image' where the 'uid' in that table is the same as the 'id' from the table 'users'...

Now....
I store the query in a session, the output that I'm having in a var_dump(); is the correct stuff....

So I stored in a session...

```
Session::put('user_img', $users_images);
```

Now, that's fine.
I request the session in my view.

```
{{ Session::get('user_img', 'none.png') }}
```

The full request is this:

```
<img style="max-width:33px;" src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/public/img/user_img/{{ Session::get('user_img', 'none.png') }}"/>
```

But that doesn't matter, because the `{{ Config::get('app.url') }}`
Always worked.

The error I' receiving is `ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Array to string conversion`
But how can I fix this error the best?

Kind regards,

Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because your session is an **array**, and you're trying to print it as a string.

Either you loop over it:

```
@foreach (Session::get('user_img') as $img) 

  <img style="max-width:33px;" src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/public/img/user_img/{{ $img }}"/>

@endforeach
```

Or you just take ONE record:

```
$users_images = DB::table('users')
->select('user_image.img')
->join('user_image','user_image.uid','=','users.id')
->first();
```

Comment: If I take just one, I get this error ´Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string´

Comment: Yeah, because it returns an object. You should do `Session::get('user_images')->img`

Answer (score 0):

I combined both, the single ->first() and the loop, now it does work, thanks alot!